# How change/create a new source type for UIImagePicker (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new in iOS development and I need help.
I use UIImagePicker so that the user selects his image.
I want that user selects pictures located in a folder of the application and not the iOS library. All this using UIImagePicker. Is this possible?
If I am wrong please redirect me to a website or tutorial.

Thank you all.

Sample code :

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var PhotoOpeningView: UIImageView!

let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func ChooseAImageBTN(sender: AnyObject) {

    let imagePickerView = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerView.delegate = self

    imagePickerView.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
    self.presentViewController(imagePickerView, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


@IBAction func btnSave(sender: UIButton) {
    let LoadSaveNo = PhotoOpeningView
    userDefaults.setObject(LoadSaveNo, forKey: "LoadSave")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}


func imagePickerController(picker :UIImagePickerController,
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info : [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        var Image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
        PhotoOpeningView.image = Image
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: folder of the application means Document root directory? It should be like when you select button pick image its should shows thumbnail of document folder all images in UIPopupover.

Comment: Yes document root directory. 
I want to integrate images into the application. When the user clicks the button can select the images. But I do not want the images in the library of his iphone.
I use UIPopupover you say?

Comment: Ok You want to access images from Application folder(means from NsBundle). You can use UIPopoverController to load all images from NSBundle. You can show images in UICollectionview and you have to create protocol and delegate to get image to your viewController. You cannot use apple UIImagePickerController. You have to make your own.

Comment: Ok thank you so much.
I will check on UIPopoverController and read the documentation.

To explain, I want to create a calendar. The user selects for each entry boxes (time of day) one of the 300 images in the folder I joined in the application.

So it's good to reach my goal ?

Comment: you can load all those 300 thumbnail size images in UICollectionViewController and you can show UICollectionViewController In UIPopoverController(like iOS style). When you select photo delegate the message to your viewController. Let me know if you need sample code I can make.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that !
Yes with pleasure I will a sample code for example to practice your method. When you have the time.

Comment: I work on the code for you this weekend

Comment: I have a question. is this iPhone or iPad app?

Comment: @arnaud  Why are you waiting on sample code from another user when there are excellent tutorial links in the answer below?

Comment: @Shashi3456643 Sorry I dont see your message.
Its for Ipad. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Thats fine this will work for both :)

Comment: @Shashi3456643, Hello :)

When I connect my button "Browse" directly to the view of CollectionView that's ok I see my pictures.
But I can not select images (normal).

When I connect the function of the button "browse" (the function you wrote me), application crash.

I know there are things to adapt for my application but I do not know what..
I may be forgetting something on my storyboard.

Comment: Not clear what exactly problem is? Can you explain me all the steps which u r doing and its crashing and also show me crash log

Comment: Sorry me, my English it's not perfect haha.

So to be clearer I applied your sample code on my application.
The application crash when I click "browse".

"buttonBrowsePhotos" functions are highlighted in green.
More precisely:
  let vc: = PhotoPickersVC array.objectAtIndex (0) as PhotoPickersVC

And when I connect the "Browse" button just Segue Action Popover presentation (without the functions you wrote me) at this time I can see my ViewCollection with my all my images, but I can not select them to attérissent in the box of the agenda.

I see nothing on the crash log I believe.

Comment: let vc: = PhotoPickersVC array.objectAtIndex (0) This is wrong statement. Your PhotoPickersVC how can it have array. In my code I have 
        var array:NSArray = nc.viewControllers as NSArray
        let vc:PhotoPickersVC=array.objectAtIndex(0) as PhotoPickersVC;
It means I am accessing nc variable is NavigationalController not ViewController. Nvaigational controller has collection of viewcontrollers not ViewController has collection of viewController assign this way let vc: = PhotoPickersVC I will work.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your commentaire.
I hurt reproduced request that your sample in the storyboard you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//This class has UIButton when you click on button it opens PhotoPickersVC. Which will show all images from your application
class ViewController: UIViewController,PhotoPickersDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView:UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    @IBAction func buttonBrowsePhotos(sender: UIButton)
    {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nc :UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PhotoNC") as UINavigationController
        var array:NSArray = nc.viewControllers as NSArray
        let vc:PhotoPickersVC=array.objectAtIndex(0) as PhotoPickersVC;
        vc.delegate=self;
        self.presentViewController(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func selectPhoto(image: UIImage)
    {
        imageView.image=image;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}



//Protocol used to send photo to ViewController class using delegate
protocol PhotoPickersDelegate
{
    func selectPhoto(var image : UIImage)
}

//This class shows all the photos of your application
class PhotoPickersVC: UICollectionViewController {
    let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
    var myImages :NSArray?
    var delegate : PhotoPickersDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var myBundle : NSBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle();
        myImages = myBundle.pathsForResourcesOfType("jpeg", inDirectory: nil);
    }

    @IBAction func buttonCancel(sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
        return myImages!.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PhotoCellCollectionViewCell
        print(cell);




        var imageName=myImages?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).lastPathComponent
        var imageName1 :NSString=imageName!
        var image:UIImage=UIImage(named: imageName1)!
        cell.imageView.image=image

        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {

        if((self.delegate) != nil)
        {
            var imageName=myImages?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).lastPathComponent
            var imageName1 :NSString=imageName!
            var image:UIImage=UIImage(named: imageName1)!

            delegate?.selectPhoto(image)
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


}



//This class used to subclass UICollectionViewCell which is used in PhotoPickersVC
class PhotoCellCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I go work with that and I give you the new !

Answer (score 0):

Having a look through [the UIImagePickerController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIImagePickerControllerSourceType), I don't think what you're asking is possible.  If you have a look at UIImagePickerControllerSourceType, you'll see there are only 3 possibilities, PhotoLibrary, SavedPhotosAlbum, or Camera, which doesn't leave a whole lot of room for trying out a source type of 'custom'.

My recommendation is to use a UICollectionView to display your images and allow your user to choose from them using collection view delegate methods.  You could whip one up quite quickly if all you need is a simple image picker.

Objective-C:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Swift:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1

Comment: Thank you but I have already seen the documentation, I wanted to know if it was possible to add options.
To make more precise, I want to create a calendar.
The user selects for each entry boxes (time of day) one of the 300 images in the folder I joined in the application.

Comment: There's no secrets outside of the documentation.  There's no way to add 'options'.  I have built a few custom calendars, and each time I've used collection views.  And for presenting your images to the user and allowing them to select, again, a collection view is your best bet.  Once you learn the collection view you will quickly be on your way to building an awesome app!

Comment: Yes I take the documentation, thank you Frankie for your help !